# memory leak - application exited with signal 9 in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an application which is utilizing a lot of memory by using UIImageView, creating graphics context, calling web service, drawing using quartz2d, blending images, playing video, recording and so on. But now the application is exiting after some time with a memory warning.
Is there any way to clear the ram usage like clear cache or something like that.

Comment: You should try to ask a more specific question. The general answer is this is an environment where you must manage memory. But it's hard to say anything more without a specific question. You should read Apple's memory management guide to start.

Answer (score 2):

First of all delete build folder from your directory,then clean all targets,then go to menu Build 
then Build and Analyze and solve the potential leaks.

After doing this you should run your application through instruments and see where memory leak occures 
and then try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You, can do one thing, put your application on leaks analyzer, and check out the leaks, and prior you go through your code and release, the allocated objects after those use have finished, by releasing them.

Here is a good tutorial. http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/